# File upload using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I just want to upload a single pdf file using cakephp,
here is my view called `pdfadd.ctp`:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('pdfadd1', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));?>
    <fieldset>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->file('Document.submittedfile');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
```

Here is my conroller:

```
 public function pdfadd(){
     if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
         //die();
         $file = $this->request->data['Document']['submittedfile'];
         //$this->pdfadd1->save($this->request->data);
         move_uploaded_file($this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/webroot/files/' . $this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name']);
     }
```

It gives me this error:

```
Warning (2): move_uploaded_file(D:/Program Files D/xampp/htdocs/app/webroot/files/Functions Package for email (1).pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP\Controller\PagesController.php, line 29]
Warning (2): move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'D:\Program Files D\xampp\tmp\php862.tmp' to 'D:/Program Files D/xampp/htdocs/app/webroot/files/Functions Package for email (1).pdf' [APP\Controller\PagesController.php, line 29]
```

And also I want to rename the file to `1.pdf`. The file should save in `webroot/files`.

Comment: I am using cakephp 2.0.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/webroot/files/' . $this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name']
```

with this:

```
WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . '1.pdf'
```

However, you really should do more validation, like using [PHP's `is_uploaded_file` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php), making sure the file really is a PDF, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
move_uploaded_file($this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['tmp_name'],      $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/webroot/files/' . $this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name']);
```

1.Change this code according to directory
2.c:xampp/htdocs(its a default location for uploading in cakephp ),then put your upload file location

```
 move_uploaded_file($this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'cakephp/app/webroot/files/' . $this->data['Document']['submittedfile']['name']);
```

3.You can rename it before uploading

Answer (score 1):

This line get only file name, not file.

```
$file = $this->request->data['Document']['submittedfile'];
```

You could use this.

```
$file = $_FILES ['Document'] ['submittedfile'];
```